# How to use Morgan logger?

Tags: node.js, logging, express

I cannot log with Morgan. It doesn't log info to console. The documentation doesn't tell how to use it.

I want to see what a variable is. This is a code from `response.js` file of expressjs framework:

```
var logger = require("morgan");

res.render = function(view, options, fn){
  options = options || {};
  var self = this;
  var req = this.req;
  var app = req.app;

  // support callback function as second arg
  if ('function' == typeof options) {
    fn = options, options = {};
  }

  // merge res.locals
  options._locals = self.locals;

  // default callback to respond
  fn = fn || function(err, str){
    if (err) return req.next(err);
    self.send(str);
  };

  // Here I want to see what fn is
  // But it doesn't show me anything in console
  // How to use it?
  logger(fn);

  // render
  app.render(view, options, fn);
};
```

How to use Morgan?

Answer (score 130):

Seems you too are confused with the same thing as I was, the reason I stumbled upon this question. I think we associate logging with manual logging as we would do in Java with log4j (if you know java) where we instantiate a Logger and say log 'this'.

Then I dug in morgan code, turns out it is not that type of a logger, it is for automated logging of requests, responses and related data. When added as a middleware to an express/connect app, by default it should log statements to stdout showing details of: remote ip, request method, http version, response status, user agent etc. It allows you to modify the log using tokens or add color to them by defining 'dev' or even logging out to an output stream, like a file.

For the purpose we thought we can use it, as in this case, we still have to use:

```
console.log(..);
```

Or if you want to make the output pretty for objects:

```
var util = require("util");
console.log(util.inspect(..));
```

Answer (score 69):

I think I have a way where you may not get exactly get what you want, but you can integrate Morgan's logging with log4js -- in other words, all your logging activity can go to the same place. I hope this digest from an Express server is more or less self-explanatory:

```
var express = require("express");
var log4js = require("log4js");
var morgan = require("morgan");
...
var theAppLog = log4js.getLogger();
var theHTTPLog = morgan({
  "format": "default",
  "stream": {
    write: function(str) { theAppLog.debug(str); }
  }
});
....
var theServer = express();
theServer.use(theHTTPLog);
```

Now you can write whatever you want to theAppLog and Morgan will write what it wants to the same place, using the same appenders etc etc. Of course, you can call info() or whatever you like in the stream wrapper instead of debug() -- that just reflects the logging level you want to give to Morgan's req/res logging.

Answer (score 45):

Morgan should not be used to log in the way you're describing. Morgan was built to do logging in the way that servers like Apache and Nginx log to the error_log or access_log. For reference, this is how you use morgan:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    morgan      = require('morgan'); // Require morgan before use

// You can set morgan to log differently depending on your environment
if (app.get('env') == 'production') {
  app.use(morgan('common', { skip: function(req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }, stream: __dirname + '/../morgan.log' }));
} else {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
```

Note the production line where you see morgan called with an options hash `{skip: ..., stream: __dirname + '/../morgan.log'}`

The `stream` property of that object determines where the logger outputs. By default it's STDOUT (your console, just like you want) but it'll only log request data. It isn't going to do what `console.log()` does.

If you want to inspect things on the fly use the built in `util` library:

```
var util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(anyObject)); // Will give you more details than console.log
```

So the answer to your question is that you're asking the wrong question. But if you still want to use Morgan for logging requests, there you go.

Comment: What do you recommend for that kind of logging?

Comment: The Debug package is what you might want. The real basic idea is that rather than using `console.log()` you can use the Debug lib anywhere in your code and you don't need to worry about removing it in production. https://github.com/visionmedia/debug

Comment: i don't get it...if an error occurs in my NodeJS app, am I *not* to record that error in a logfile using morgan? or winston, or bunyan? if not then what would i use for that?

Comment: The OP implied that he wants to use Morgan to inspect data and debug his app in development which should really be done with something like the Debug module. You absolutely should log errors to a file in production. If you set up your app as I suggest in my answer above then errors get logged to a file in production and to the console in development. Does that clear things up?

Answer (score 21):

I faced the same problem ago and instead, I used winston. As fellas above said, morgan is for automated logging of request/response. Winston can be configured pretty much same way as log4Net/log4J, has severity levels, different streams to which you can log etc.

For example:

`npm install winston`

Then, if you call the below code somewhere on you application initialization:

```
var winston = require('winston');

// setup default logger (no category)
winston.loggers.add('default', {
    console: {
        colorize: 'true',
        handleExceptions: true,
        json: false,
        level: 'silly',
        label: 'default',
    },
    file: {
        filename: 'some/path/where/the/log/file/reside/default.log',
        level: 'silly',
        json: false,
        handleExceptions: true,
    },
});

//
// setup logger for category `usersessions`
// you can define as many looggers as you like
//
winston.loggers.add('usersessions', {
    console: {
        level: 'silly',
        colorize: 'true',
        label: 'usersessions',
        json: false,
        handleExceptions: true,
    },
    file: {
        filename: 'some/path/where/the/log/file/reside/usersessions.log',
        level: 'silly',
        json: false,
        handleExceptions: true,
    },
});
```

note: before calling above code, winston.loggers is empty, i.e you dont have any loggers configured yet. Pretty much like Log4Net/J XmlConfigure methods - you need to first call them, to init your logging.

Then, later wherever in you application server side code you may do:

```
var winston = require('winston');
// log instances as defined in first snippet
var defaultLog = winston.loggers.get('default'); 
var userSessionsLog = winston.loggers.get('usersessions');

defaultLog.info('this goes to file default.log');
userSessionsLog.debug('this goes to file usersessions.log')
```

Hope that helps.

for further documentation reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston

Comment: I must say, for developers switching from Java type languages to MEAN stack, this will make them comfortable and familiar. Thanks

Comment: can you tell me how can i access this log file when my app is deployed, actually i want to save log file on cloud storage but not able to find a proper way

Answer (score 10):

Morgan :- 
Morgan is a middleware which will help us to identify the clients who are accessing our application. Basically a logger.

To Use Morgan, We need to follow below steps :-

1. Install the morgan using below command:

`npm install --save morgan`

This will add morgan to json.package file

2. Include the morgan in your project

`var morgan = require('morgan');`

3> // create a write stream (in append mode)

```
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(
      path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), {flags: 'a'}
 );
// setup the logger 
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));
```

Note:
Make sure you do not plumb above blindly make sure you have every 
conditions where you need .

Above will automatically create a access.log file to your root once user will access your app.

Answer (score 8):

```
var express = require('express');

var fs = require('fs');

var morgan = require('morgan')

var app = express();

// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log',{flags: 'a'});


// setup the logger
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}))


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
});
```

[example nodejs + express + morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)

Answer (score 4):

In my case:

```
-console.log()  // works
-console.error() // works
-app.use(logger('dev')) // Morgan is NOT logging requests that look like "GET /myURL 304 9.072 ms - -"
```

FIX: I was using Visual Studio code, and I had to add this to my Launch Config

```
"outputCapture": "std"
```

Suggestion, in case you are running from an IDE, run directly from the command line to make sure the IDE is not causing the problem.

Comment: Isn't `console.log()` writing to standard output also?

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs, you can use a [predefined](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#using-a-predefined-format-string) method to log request data

```js
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
```

Suppose you want to log a post request data, you could make a [custom token](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#using-a-custom-format-function) and use it like this

```js
morgan.token('postData', (request) => {
  if (request.method == 'POST') return ' ' + JSON.stringify(request.body);
  else return ' ';
});

app.use(
  morgan(
    ':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms :postData'
  )
);
```

This will log a POST request in the console as

```sh
POST /api/test2 409 33 - 0.253 ms  {"name":"Test name","number":"323-322-55"}
```

**Note** - You should never log request data as it may violate local privacy law (e.g. GDPR in EU) or business-standard. This is just an example

Comment: This answer is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Using morgan is pretty much straightforward. As the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#using-a-predefined-format-string) suggests, there are different ways to get your desired output with morgan. It comes with  preconfigured logging methods  or you can define one yourself. Eg.

> const morgan = require('morgan')
>
> app.use(morgan('tiny')

This will give you the preconfiguration called tiny. You will notice in your terminal what it does.
In case you are not satisfied with this and you want deeper e.g. lets say the request url, then this is where tokens come in.

> morgan.token('url', function (req, res){
> return '/api/myendpoint'
> })

then use it like so:

> app.use(morgan(' :url ')

Check the documentation its all highlighted there.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
```

and it will work.

Comment: Do you know how i can use morgan to save to send the data through an http request? like another apps api responsible for storing the logs

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [mongo-morgan-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-morgan-ext)

The usage is:

```
var logger = require('mongo-morgan-ext');

var db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDB';

var collection = 'Logs'

var skipfunction = function(req, res) {

return res.statusCode > 399;
} //Thiw would skip if HTTP request response is less than 399 i.e no errors.

app.use(logger(db,collection,skipfunction)); //In your express-application
```

The expected output is

```
{
    "RequestID": "",
    "status": "",
    "method": "",
    "Remote-user": "",
    "Remote-address": "",
    "URL": "",
    "HTTPversion": "",
    "Response-time": "",
    "date":"",
    "Referrer": "",
    "REQUEST": { //10
        "Accept": "",
        "Accept-Charset": "",
        "Accept-Encoding": "",
        "Accept-Language": "",
        "Authorization": "",
        "Cache-Control": "",
        "Connection": "",
        "Cookie": "",
        "Content-Length": "",
        "Content-MD5": "",
        "Content-Type": "",
        "Expect": "",
        "Forwarded": "",
        "From": "",
        "Host": "",
        "Max-Forwards": "",
        "Origin": "",
        "Pragma": "",
        "Proxy-Authorization": "",
        "Range": "",
        "TE": "",
        "User-Agent": "",
        "Via": "",
        "Warning": "",
        "Upgrade": "",
        "Referer": "",
        "Date": "",
        "X-requested-with": "",
        "X-Csrf-Token": "",
        "X-UIDH": "",
        "Proxy-Connection": "",
        "X-Wap-Profile": "",
        "X-ATT-DeviceId": "",
        "X-Http-Method-Override":"",
        "Front-End-Https": "",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "",
        "X-Forwarded-Host": "",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "",
        "DNT": "",
        "Accept-Datetime": "",
        "If-Match": "",
        "If-Modified-Since": "",
        "If-None-Match": "",
        "If-Range": "",
        "If-Unmodified-Since": ""
    },
    "RESPONSE": {
        "Status": "",
        "Content-MD5":"",
        "X-Frame-Options": "",
        "Accept-Ranges": "",
        "Age": "",
        "Allow": "",
        "Cache-Control": "",
        "Connection": "",
        "Content-Disposition": "",
        "Content-Encoding": "",
        "Content-Language": "",
        "Content-Length": "",
        "Content-Location": "",
        "Content-Range": "",
        "Content-Type":"",
        "Date":"",
        "Last-Modified": "",
        "Link": "",
        "Location": "",
        "P3P": "",
        "Pragma": "",
        "Proxy-Authenticate": "",
        "Public-Key-Pins": "",
        "Retry-After": "",
        "Server": "",
        "Trailer": "",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "",
        "TSV": "",
        "Upgrade": "",
        "Vary": "",
        "Via": "",
        "Warning": "",
        "WWW-Authenticate": "",
        "Expires": "",
        "Set-Cookie": "",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "",
        "Refresh":"",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "",
        "X-XSS-Protection": "",
        "X-WebKit-CSP":"",
        "X-Content-Security-Policy": "",
        "Content-Security-Policy": "",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "",
        "X-Powered-By": "",
        "X-UA-Compatible": "",
        "X-Content-Duration": "",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "",
        "X-Request-ID": "",
        "ETag": "",
        "Accept-Patch": ""
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want get logs in your terminal, you can simply use

`app.use(morgan('dev'));`