# Why use both `morgan` and `debug` logging packages in one project

Tags: node.js, express

I've just created an app from express generator and it uses two loggers `debug` and `morgan`:

**/bin/www.js**

```
const debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
....
server.on('listening', onListening);
function onListening() {
    const addr = server.address();
    const bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
 --^^^^^^^--
}
```

**/app.js**

```
var logger = require('morgan');
...
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

Why use both? Can't only one of them be used for both purposes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`morgan` is a library you typically attach as middleware, and then it automatically logs information as requests flow through your system, especially in regards to [timing](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/58a7f26ec699fef99e3ed11209503367fa3d2c9c/index.js#L104-L111) it seems. I don't believe it is something you would typically invoke manually for additional logging.

`debug` is something you would add in manually with additional information that `morgan` doesn't necessarily know or care about. You can also turn `debug` logging on and off through the use of a regular expression in an environment variable, which is useful for limiting namespaced logs down to the ones you care about when debugging an issue. See [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#usage).

So sure, you could use `debug` to log the same way and the same things `morgan` does, but you'd have to do it all by hand (for better or worse).

Comment: thanks, but I could easily write a function with `debug()` inside and add it as a middleware. there's got to be something else

Comment: That's [pretty much it](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/58a7f26ec699fef99e3ed11209503367fa3d2c9c/index.js#L129-L130). You'd also need your own timing methods for tracking how long requests take, and if you wanted to completely mimic `morgan`, the ability to change logging [formats](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/58a7f26ec699fef99e3ed11209503367fa3d2c9c/index.js#L152).

Comment: thanks, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494956/how-to-use-morgan-logger) thread explains many things about `morgan`. I liked this particularly this explanation: `Morgan was built to do logging in the way that servers like Apache and Nginx log to the error_log or access_log.`. You may want to add some details from the thread to your answer.